# Cant acces to form label text

Tags: c++

How to change label text? With hints what i get from c++ it dosnt work

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());

    Form1().label1->Text = "TEST"; //How to change label text?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this c++cli, please retag if so

Comment: `Form1()` creates a new object if you weren't aware.

Comment: Something like that?

gcnew forma = Form1();
Application::Run(forma);

Bot how acces now, it dont show any hints

Answer (score 0):

Do it in constructor or Load event of `Form1` class that you wrote. Keep this code as is (i.e. don't change any property from here). Property of a form or any control should not be changed from `main` function (ideally).